# Pyglet.gl has no attribute glTranslatef

Tags: python, pyglet

I have just started working with pyglet trying to make a simple game as a hobby. However, I have run into an issue. I am working with this demo:

https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/pyglet-1.5-maintenance/examples/window/camera.py

and I am getting the error:

`AttributeError: module 'pyglet.gl' has no attribute 'glTranslatef'`.

I was wondering if anyone might have some ideas as why this might happen. I have installed pyglet using `pip install pyglet` and I am running on a MacBook if that matters.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `pyglet`, but the latest published version is 2.0.6 (found [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyglet/)) and you are using an example from version 1.5. So, it is likely that the library has made some changes to what things are called.

You should use an example from the version you installed, instead.

Comment: Ah I see, was rushed and just copied the example on my way out the door without paying attention. I’ll check it out and see if it works

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you!